# wrap over iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got an iframe and input field with suggest in it.
The list of suggested items is created in js with follows params:

```
{
  borderRadius : '2px',
  boxShadow : '3px 4px 8px #DDDDDD',
  background : '#fff',
  border : '#aaa 1px solid',
  fontSize : '12px',
  padding : '2px',
  textAlign : 'left',
  position : 'absolute'
}
```

And it works fine while the list is not too long: now i see something like shown on the picture:
[image: iframe]
Suggest list is longer than iframe.

So the question is: how can i make this list to appear over the iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An iframe is like an embedded window, everything in it is displayed inside it.
A workaround will be like specify a definite height for the list and add overflow property in it, so that the list will be displayed inside the iframe but will have a scroll bar.

Comment: Correct but based on the screenshot he is already doing that.

Comment: @user357320 : i think that scroll bar belong to the iframe not list.

Comment: Do you mean then putting a height on the list itself ?  Ok, I understand, that might work.

Comment: @user357320 : yea that's what i told.. :)

Comment: @Exor seems to be fine :) i mean - that's not i wanted to, but i guess it's the best approach

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

What you can do is to inject the contents of the iframe file into the main page.  Take a look at this:  http://api.jquery.com/load/ It will only work though if the pages are in the same domain.  Then just put a div instead of the iframe and .load into it.

Comment: Hm... Unfortunantely i can't do that - i need it to be an iframe